# Using NLA editor for an armature, the animation breaks up. how can it be fixed?

Tags: animation, armature, nla-editor

I used the NLA editor to put two actions (the second one was a walk cycles action) together to fix the position of the armature in the second action. The position got fixed, but the walk cycles wrecked up (the legs went side to side instead of back and forth).

I also tried fixing the position by moving the keyframes of the walk cycles on the Y-axis in the graph editor, but I got the same results.

blend file: ufile.io/kt9zq7dw

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://ufile.io/kt9zq7dw

Comment: for the top strip you've chosen Blending > Combine, so the keyframes will combine with the ones that are part of the strip below, that must be the reason why you don't see exactly what you expected

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you haven't created keyframes for the top strip, the one of the strip below will play

Comment: Thank you. But I need to set it to combine so that the walk cycle wouldn't happen in the middle of the scene but in the bone's previous position.

Comment: yes but the bones called Bone, Bone_L007 and Bone_R007 will be rotated as they are in the strip below. What you could do is keyframe these bones the way you want at the beginning of the second strip.

Comment: Thank you .....

Comment: have you fixed your problem?

Comment: Yes, adding three more bones and using child of constraint.